# Stuck in initramfs

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Earlier today I was downloading some files with smbclient, after downloading I did rm -rf * in the directory that had downloaded files but after that my terminal go inside // I wasnt able to run any command ls ( I was getting error /bin/ls not found). So I restarted my VM and now I am stuck in initramfs. I read some online solutions telling me to do fsck /dev/sda1. I did  but the drive is busy and is already mounted on /root. Inside /root I have all the data intact. Now how can I fix this or atleast get everything inside /opt & my home directory restored. I think I can get the data of my directory back by mounting vmdk ?

Comment: What directory did you do the remove in?

Comment: @Torin ~/Documents/htb/Arkham/smbdata/

Comment: No VM snapshots?